# How do accumulate functions actually work?

Tags: drools

Let's say we have the next example :

There are certain products that belong to certain product groups, and we want the total price summed up in an logical fact as either the products in the product group change or as their price changes.

```
private class ProductGroup {
    private String name;
}

public class Product {
   private ProductGroup productGroup;
   private int price;
}
```

This is the class that will be intended for the logical facts that will get inserted by the summation rule in Drools.

```
private class ProductGroupTotalPrice {
   private ProductGroup productGroup;
   private int totalPrice;
}
```

There is a rule that sums up the total price for a given ProductGroup.

```
rule "total price for product group"
    when
        $productGroup : ProductGroup()
        $totalPrice : Number() from accumulate(
           Product(productGroup == $productGroup, $price : price),
           sum($price)
        )
    then
        insertLogical(new ProductGroupTotalPrice($productGroup, $totalPrice));
end
```

So my question is what will the logic be when Products from a given ProductGroup are added/deleted from the working memory, they change the ProductGroup or their price is being changed?
- Lets say that the summation is done at the beggining of the application based on the current state and the logical fact is inserted into the working memory with the total price. Then the price for one Product is changed at one point so the totalPrice needs to be updated.

Here are three cases how the process would possibly be done :

1. Incrementally with doing a constant time calculation. Only take into account the change that has happened and subtract the old price from the total and add the new one for the one Product that was changed. (Excelent)
2. The whole summation is done again but the Product instances that meet the criteria(that are from the given ProductGroup) are already known, they are not searched for. (Good)
3. Besides the summation a loop through all the Product instances in the working memory is done to see which ones meet the criteria(that are from the given ProductGroup). (Bad)

Is the logic that is implemented one of these three cases or it is something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the documentation of the other form of accumulate, i.e., the one where you can define the steps for initialization, processings (note the plural!) and returning an arbitrary function. Some functions permit the reverse operation so that removing a fact that has been used for computing the function result can be handled: e.g., 'sum'. (But compare 'max'.)

So I think that your accumulate pattern will be updated efficiently.

However, I think that this does not mean that your logically inserted `ProductGroupTotalPrice` will be updated. (Try it, I may be wrong.)

I would use a simple rule

```
rule "total price for product group"
when
    $productGroup: ProductGroup()
    Number( $totalPrice: intValue ) from accumulate(
       Product(productGroup == $productGroup, $price : price),
       sum($price)
    )
    $pgtp: ProductGroupTotalPrice( productGroup == $productGroup,
                                   totalPrice != $totalPrice )
                            
then
    modify( $pgtp ){ setTotalPrice( $totalPrice ) }
end
```

and an addition rule to insert an initial `ProductGroupTotalPrice` for the product group with totalPrice 0.

Comment: Excellent example Laune, but don't understand what "totalPric != $totalPrice" means? thanks

Comment: It "means" that I was sloppy and misspelled the fields of class ProductGroupTotalPrice. (Edited my answer.)

Comment: No. I'm pretty new to drools and don't understand why the unequal condition is there? what is it for? what does it mean? I didn't even notice the typo.

Comment: The fact representing a Product Groups Total Price must be updated if the recalculation resulting in Number(...) yields a different price. This is a customarily used way of avoiding a cascade of more rules firing if the fact is updated needlessly with the same price.